# Where can I find older versions of chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently upgraded to chrome 40; and this version of chrome disallows connections to servers using sslv3. But for my internal work, I have to connect to such an internal server (the server admins know about the problem; but basically they are very busy right now; and they will not update this server for some more weeks). So I am basically broken - I can't get to that machine.

So I thought to simply fetch the chrome v39 DEBs from somewhere, install that and keep it pinned for the next weeks.

But well; I haven't found this "somewhere" yet. When I try to browse to "http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/" there is just a 404 error.

Any idea, anybody?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have older version on this [site](http://google-chrome.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu/old)